# Application crash after moving from .NET 3.5 to .NET 4.0

Tags: c#, .net

Recently I upgraded .NET from 3.5 to 4.0 in my desktop application. On my development machine it works fine.

On some production machines it crashes right at start.

1. Windows 8.1, Windows 7

   > Problem Event Name:    APPCRASH 
   >   Application Name:    myApp.exe 
   >   Application Version:    2.0.0.0 
   >   Application Timestamp:    553a56e8 
   >   Fault Module Name:    KERNELBASE.dll 
   >   Fault Module Version:    6.3.9600.17415 
   >   Fault Module Timestamp:    54504ade 
   >   Exception Code:    e0434f4d 
   >   Exception Offset:    00014598 
   >   OS Version:    6.3.9600.2.0.0.256.4 
   >   Locale ID:    1045
2. Windows XP SP3 with .NET 4.0

> Faulting application myApp.exe, version 2.0.0.0, stamp 553a56e8,
>   faulting module kernel32.dll, version 5.1.2600.6532, stamp 53203b53,
>   debug? 0, fault address 0x00012fd3.

[image]

Please note that the source is **.NET Runtime 2.0 Error**. Why?

The application is compiled in .NET 4.0, which is installed on the machine.

Another (much smaller and simpler) application from this solution, which is also compiled for .NET 4.0 works fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like a rogue reference in your web.config, can you post that?

Comment: .net 4.0 runs on top of .net 2.0

Comment: @recursive .NET 4 **does not** run on top of .NET 2.0. Only 3.0 and 3.5 do.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to change the runtime .NET version in file `App.config`/`web.config` to:

```
<startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
</startup>
```